# Use nested loops and regex to break down files by date

Tags: python, regex, csv, nltk

I have a folder filled with text documents and I would like to write a script that breaks up each text file into sets of three words, counts those sets, and then writes it to a csv file like this: "date, set of three words, frequency, relative frequency." Each text file has a title that looks something like this:

```
2014.5.30RNC Chairman Priebus Statement.txt
2012.8.17Homeless Veterans Need More From Obama.txt
2012.9.6GLARING OMISSION #16/ Shinseki Glosses.txt
```

I wrote the script below and it does nothing but it also doesn't spit out an error message. I think that means there's something wrong with my regex or the nested loops but I don't know how to solve this without an error message. Thank you in advance for any help!

```
corpus_root = '/Users/jolijttamanaha/Desktop/thesis2/RNC/Data2'

for year in range(2015, 1990, 1):
    for month in range(12, 9, 1):
        speeches = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, r'^{}\.{}\.\d*[\s\S]*'.format(year,month))
        raw = speeches.raw().lower()
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw.encode('utf-8').translate(None, string.punctuation))
        tgs = nltk.trigrams(tokens) 
        fdist = nltk.FreqDist(tgs) 
        minscore = 1
        numwords = len(raw)    
        print "Words in corpus:" 
        print numwords
        c = csv.writer(open("RNCngramsbymonth.csv", "a"))
        for k,v in fdist.items():
            if v > minscore:
                rf = Decimal(v)/Decimal(numwords)
                firstword, secondword, thirdword = k #splits up the list hidden in k 
                trigram = firstword + " " + secondword + " " + thirdword #turns the list in k into one string
                time = year + month
                results = time,trigram,v,rf 
                c.writerow(results)
                print firstword, secondword, thirdword, v, rf

        print "Done with month {}".format(month)
```